# Choosing "From" field using python win32com outlook

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to automate emails using python. Unfortunately, the network administrators at my work have blocked SMTP relay, so I cannot use that approach to send the emails (they are addressed externally).

I am therefore using win32com to automatically send these emails via outlook. This is working fine except for one thing. I want to choose the "FROM" field within my python code, but I simply cannot figure out how to do this.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you configured a separate POP3/SMTP account, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property to an account from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection.

If you are sending on behalf of an Exchange user, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property

Comment: SentOnBehalfOfName worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: interesting, SendUsingAccount does not work but this does.

Comment: @Julius - then it is a good idea to ask a new question and describe in detail your particular environment.