# SentOnBehalfOfName is not working properly

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to send mail from another account (which is configured in my outlook but not default account) using the below code. The problem is when i keep mail.display(True) it is showing the account name but when i keep the mail.send instead of mail.display(True) the mail going from the default account.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = 'xyz@gmail.com'
mail.To = 'mymail@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Hello'
mail.HTMLBody = template
mail.send
```

Comment: Have you tried the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454538/choosing-from-field-using-python-win32com-outlook ; it looks like SentOnBehalfOfName may only work with other exchange users, and SendUsingAccount should be used for other POP3/SMTP accounts.

As an additional sanity check - does the user have the correct permissions to use sendAs? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user)